# Migrating SQL Server stored procedures to hadoop ecosystem

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, hadoop, mapreduce

I am interested in migrating an existing Microsoft SQL Server system with a lot of stored procedures to the hadoop ecosystem. Is there an existing tool/tool suggestion that is good for migrating the stored procedures to the hadoop eco system ?

Comment: According to the docs at Cloudera http://www.cloudera.com/content/dam/cloudera/documents/Using-Cloudera-to-Improve-Data-Processing_WP_2012-09.pdf many stored proces will work directly, but I wasn't able to find any specific tools either.

Comment: Thanks for that, it is helpful.